# Updating multiple rows (quantities in a cart) in a form using Webmatrix/Razor

Tags: sql, forms, razor, webmatrix

I have a cart solution I'm building for a client, and I'm stuck with the basket. The basket is created using 2 tables, CartID and CartItems.

On the Basket page, I just read in the items for the cart and display them:

```
var basketowner = Request.Cookies["cart"].Value;
var basket = db.Query("SELECT * FROM CartItems WHERE CartID=@0", basketowner);
```

These are then listed as so:

```
<form action="" method="post">
@foreach(var row in basket){

        <div class="basketcolumn1">@row.ProductID<input type="hidden" value="@row.CartItemID" name="LineID" /></div>
        <div class="basketcolumn2">@row.ProductTitle @row.ProductOrientation</div>
        <div class="basketcolumn3">@row.ProductSize</div>
        <div class="basketcolumn1"><input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" maxlength="2"value="@row.quantity" style="width: 20px;" /></div>
        <div class="basketcolumn4">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="basketcolumn5">@currencysymbol.Currency@row.Price</div>
        <div class="basketcolumn6"><a href="~/Basket-Delete/@row.CartItemID" class="basketdelete">x</a></div>
        <div class="basketcolumn6"><a href="~/Basket-Update/@row.CartItemID">Update</a></div>

        <div class="clear"></div>
    }

<input type="submit" value="Update" id="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

What  need to do is submit each of the quantities back to the CartItems table and update. Is there a way to do this with a single form?

If not, can I submit the form variable (quantity) to a seperate page to update one at a time?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try a solution like this one:

assign `ProductId` as `name` to each input field

```
<input type="text" id="quantity" name="@row.ProductID" maxlength="2" 
    value="@row.quantity" style="width: 20px;" />
```

in `if (IsPost)` scan input fields and update your table

```
if(IsPost){
  foreach (string key in Request.Form){
    db.Execute(@"UPDATE CartItems SET quantity = @0 WHERE CartID = @1 AND
        ProductID = @2", Request.Form[key], basketowner, key);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering - I've placed the code in the page but get the error:  'Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '31,34' to data type int.' I tried setting key as Var or Int, but both failed. Can you suggest a remedy?

Comment: @Acteon, on which command do you have that exception? Why '31,34', aren't your ProductIDs integers?

Comment: 31, 34 are the unique primary key ID's for the rows in the CartItem database. Line error is:

Line 24: db.Execute(@"UPDATE CartItems SET quantity = @0 WHERE CartID = @1 AND

I can't see why it would fail to see the inputs as Int's when that's how they're set in the database.

Comment: Got it. Changed "Request.Form[key]" to "Request.Form[key].AsInt()" and it updated the rows like a charm. Thanks GmG, can't tell you how much I appreciate your help with this, really helped me out :)